# postgres driver connection error in python code

Tags: python, postgresql, odbc, database-connection, pyodbc

I am getting below error in my code.

`error ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'odbc-postgresql' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)`

I checked using this command `apt-cache search postgres odbc`,and found

> odbc-postgresql - ODBC driver for PostgreSQL

I debug the code line by line and found error on

```
conn1=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};SERVER='+obj[dev]['HOST']+';PORT=5432;DATABASE='+obj[dev]['DATABSE']+';UID='+obj[dev]['USER']+';PWD='+obj[dev]['PASS']+';');
```

Great help if anyone give solution on this.

Comment: Start by running `odbcinst -j` and check the `DRIVERS` line to see where it is looking for "odbcinst.ini". Then check the contents of that file to see if it contains a definition for `[PostgreSQL ANSI]`.

Comment: The "odbcinst.ini" file is empty. What should I add in that file? and if access is denied for me what commands will work?

Comment: How did you install the driver? I just did `sudo apt install odbc-postgresql` and it automatically updated "/etc/odbcinst.ini" for me like [this](https://pastebin.com/ZbtKHMEk)

Comment: when I try for sudo apt install odbc-postgresql got an below error 'The following packages have unmet dependencies: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). ' 
Complete [error](https://pastebin.com/B29YVHRT)